# JDBC: Get table names involved in a SQL query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Is there any way to know the name of the tables involved in a SQL query executed via JDBC?

For example:

```
SELECT r.roleId FROM User u, UserRole r where r.userId = u.userId and u.name = "Jonh Smith"
```

I don't want only the result set of this query but the actual table names ("User" and "Role"). I don't care about view names, but if there is no way to get the underlying table used in the view it's not a big problem, but this has to work with nested queries.

As for why I need this information it's because I am making a platform that lets other developers build applications on top of it. In my platform I let other developers register their own queries and I store them in a database. I don't want the developers to have to bother with actually manually registering the table names along with the query itself. So at the time I am executing the query I do not really know what that query is doing.

Comment: No offense, but what you describe ("I let other developers register their own queries and I store them in a database ... So at the time I am executing the query I do not really know what that query is doing.") is a SQL injection waiting to happen.

Comment: @BrianRoach Well I should have said it on the question, the other developers are not going to run their applications on my servers. Each "customization" of my platform will be deployed separately by the developers themselves. So I can trust that the queries are not going to be exploited. A normal user of the application will not have access to the queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found out how to do exactly what you need but I'm going to post this anyway since it's too long to be a comment.  The closest thing I've found is the [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html).

[This is a tutorial on how to get it.](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-meta-data-get-tables.shtml)  But that tutorial doesn't show how to get the table names.  The method to do that is called `getTableName`.

```
/**
 * Gets the designated column's table name. 
 *
 * @param column the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...
 * @return table name or "" if not applicable
 * @exception SQLException if a database access error occurs
 */
String getTableName(int column) throws SQLException;
```

I think you'll have to iterate through all the columns and put the table names in a `Set`.  The result should be all the tables used but... the problem is, if the column isn't exposed in the select, then you won't be able to discover the table.  I haven't been able to find a way around this.

Comment: Hm, I was not very hopeful to get a solution when I asked the question, but this would actually work on my case. I have another problem though, in my platform I let the developers provide the .jar of the JDBC drivers they are using. So I have no guarantees that the JDBC driver they are using are 100% compatible with the spec, can I trust this ResultSetMetaData to be properly implemented in all major drivers?

Comment: Be careful, because some drivers doesn't implement methods like this. For example, getTableName returns null when using official driver for Redshift.

Comment: Have you got the solution, I am trying to create a framework component, where I have access to SQL query & preparedStatement, (Update/Delete/insert) I want to know the table name. I cant use `getResultSet().getMetadata().getTableName()`. on insert/update/delete statements.

Answer (score 4):

The [JSQLParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) library (LGPL V2.1) seems to be capable of doing exactly what is required:

[Extract table names from SQL](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-parsing#extract-table-names-from-sql)

```
Statement statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE1");
Select selectStatement = (Select) statement;
TablesNamesFinder tablesNamesFinder = new TablesNamesFinder();
Set<String> tableList = tablesNamesFinder.getTables(selectStatement);
```